# Unable to install install4j on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: install4j

When I try to install install4j - I get an error that the installer is corrupted.  This is from the .DMG file that I just downloaded from the install4j website.  I have tried redownloading the file and still get the same issue.  Has anyone seen this issue.  I asked here because this is where the install4j website directed me.

Comment: We don't see any problem here on Mac OS X 10.8. Please re-download and make sure that no proxy cache is used. If this problem persists, please contact support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the Gatekeeper was not allowing to install the app.  I had to go to Security and check that I want to allow installs from untrusted sources.